# DRBD Compare Local and Remote before sync

Tags: drbd

Is there a way for DRBD to first compare the local and remote mirror partitions to verify which one is newer before a sync is done?

Basically what happens is that I was running Partition 1 for a week with Partition 2 off. Then I turned Partition 1 off and turned Partition 2 on. When I turned Partition 1 on while Partition 2 was on, it synced Partition 2 to Partition overwriting files generated during the week that Partition 1 was on.

I may be misunderstanding the syncing process of DRBD. But I was hoping there's a way that DRBD would through up a warning when it sees a big difference between the mirror partition and ask the Admin to choose which partition to make primary.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe should have triggered a split-brain within DRBD. DRBD should, by default, log this split-brain and refuse to connect. This is to then allow an admin to decide which node to make the split-brain "victim" and sync from the "survivor".

You can configure automatic split-brain recovery, but it is not default. I suspect you may have this configured given what you describe. See the DRBD user's guide for more information on split-brains and recovery.

https://docs.linbit.com/docs/users-guide-8.4/#s-split-brain-notification-and-recovery